# How can I run Ubuntu installer from a USB ? I am not able to run this normally. My system runs in this strange mode (screenshot)

Tags: system-installation

There is screenshot of what I can see right after boot-up.

[image]

Another photo.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfJxr.jpg)

Some info:
Ubuntu 16.04
Asus E200HA
I have used built-in Ubuntu tool,
My chipset is Cherry Trail.

I have arrived normaly right after reboot. My tool was normal ubuntu pre installed tool. My chip is intel atom, cherry trial graphics.

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu _Server_? That's just like "regular" Ubuntu but without a GUI. You should use "Ubuntu Desktop" instead, i.e. create another USB stick from an Ubuntu Desktop *.iso instead.

Comment: Please tell us which Ubuntu iso file that you downloaded, how you created the USB boot drive (which tool you used) and what computer it is (brand name and model and graphics chip/card). Knowing that will help us help you.

Comment: What @sudodus means is: did you download something like `ubuntu-16.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso` or something like `ubuntu-16.04.4-server-amd64.iso`? Notice the difference: `…desktop…` vs. `…server…`. Looks like you wanted `…desktop…` (with GUI) but instead downloaded and installed `…server…` (without GUI).

Comment: Thanks for the details. But I still have to ask about the ubuntu tool. Was it the Startup Disk Creator or another tool? And do you know about the graphics chip/card? Finally, how did you arrive at the screen shown in your first screenshot, https://i.stack.imgur.com/69taV.jpg ? Please describe by adding text to your original question.

Comment: sonething like lubuntu LTS 16.04.4

Comment: So you boot Lubuntu in text mode? Yes, it is strange. I see via https://www.cnet.com/products/asus-vivobook-e200ha-us01-11-6-atom-x5-z8300-2-gb-ram-32-gb-ssd/specs/ that there should be Intel graphics, which is usually working well with Ubuntu, but the Atom processors are special (and usually weak). I don't know about this one. Maybe you have better luck with Lubuntu 17.10.1 which is a newer version or Lubuntu 16.04.1 LTS which is an older version. See this link, [How to select the version and flavour of Ubuntu](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13540865#post13540865)

Comment: Did you check with md5sum, that the downloaded iso file is good? See this link, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes

Answer (score 0):

I just did this...
After you put the USB stick containing the ISO file in, boot your system and get into the BIOS. When you look at your boot options, you should see the USB stick (mine showed Kingston Traveler). Make this the number one boot option, save the settings under Exit tab and reboot. 
It should read the ISO file on the stick and boot from there.

-mot